# Sorting a HashMap based on date, How to reconstruct it back?

Tags: java

I am trying to sort a Hash Map based on date. (Only Month and Day, year not relevant in sorting but relevant in key). 
My Hash Map:

```
static HashMap<Date, List<String>> Hash = new HashMap<Date, List<String>>(); 

static List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Logic:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        li.add("1"); 
        li.add("2"); 
        li.add("3"); 
        li.add("4"); 
        li.add("5"); 

        Date D1 = funx("1999-04-04"); 
        Date D2 = funx("1999-01-03"); 
        Date D3 = funx("1999-03-03"); 
        Date D4 = funx("1999-08-05"); 
        Date D5 = funx("1999-12-25"); 

        Hash.put(D1, li); 
        Hash.put(D2, li); 
        Hash.put(D3, li); 
        Hash.put(D4, li); 
        Hash.put(D5, li); 



        for (Map.Entry<Date, List<String>> entry : Hash.entrySet()) {

            Date key = entry.getKey(); 
            List value = entry.getValue(); 

            System.out.println("The key: "+key);
            System.out.println("The Comparison: "+compx(key));

        }
    }




    public static Date funx(String S){

        String DateStr = S;
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(DateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());

        return d1; 
    }


    public static int compx(Date o){

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(getCurrentDate());
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.setTime(o);



        int month1 = cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1; 
        int month2 = cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

        System.out.println("Current Month: "+month1);
        System.out.println("Comparing With Month: "+month2); 

        if(month1 < month2) 
            return -1;
        else if(month1 == month2) {
            System.out.println("Current Month"+cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
            System.out.println("Is ot be subtracted"+cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
            return cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }
        else return 1; 

    }

    public static Date getCurrentDate() {
        String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        String DateStr = formattedDate;
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(DateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Date dx = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
        return dx;
    }

}
```

Now I get the return values, that is for comparison but how to reconstruct the Map again so that it is sorted?

Comment: Why not use a `TreeMap`?

Comment: Because my friend, year is not a criteria. **Unfortunately**

Comment: You can provide your own `compareTo` (for the `TreeMap`) method to avoid the criteria. (or implements `Comparable`)

Comment: Aye Cappn, any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sorting, use `TreeMap` with custom Comparator to consider month and day,

```
  Map<Date, List<String>> Hash= new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Date>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
            Calendar first = Calendar.getInstance();
            first.setTime(o1);
            Calendar second = Calendar.getInstance();
            second.setTime(o2);
            int month1 = first.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int month2 = second.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            if (month1 != month2) {
                return month1 - month2;
            } else {
                int day1 = first.get(Calendar.DATE);
                int day2 = second.get(Calendar.DATE);
                return day1 - day2;
            }
        }
    });
```

### Updated with Full Code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
    li.add("1"); 
    li.add("2"); 
    li.add("3"); 
    li.add("4"); 
    li.add("5"); 
    Map<Date, List<String>> Hash = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Date>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
            Calendar first = Calendar.getInstance();
            first.setTime(o1);
            Calendar second = Calendar.getInstance();
            second.setTime(o2);
            int month1 = first.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int month2 = second.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            if (month1 != month2) {
                return month2 - month1;
            } else {
                int day1 = first.get(Calendar.DATE);
                int day2 = second.get(Calendar.DATE);
                return day2 - day1;
            }
        }
    });

    Date D1 = funx("1999-04-04");
    Date D2 = funx("1999-01-03");
    Date D3 = funx("1999-03-03");
    Date D4 = funx("1999-08-05");
    Date D5 = funx("1999-12-25");

    Hash.put(D1, li);
    Hash.put(D2, li);
    Hash.put(D3, li);
    Hash.put(D4, li);
    Hash.put(D5, li);

    for (Map.Entry<Date, List<String>> entry: Hash.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println( entry.getKey() +" "+entry.getValue());
    }        
}

public static Date funx(String S) {

    String DateStr = S;
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(DateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());

    return d1;
}
```

### Output:

```
1999-12-25 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1999-08-05 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1999-04-04 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1999-03-03 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1999-01-03 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Could you please help me understand this? I am new to comparator.

Comment: @user2822178, Just put Date and list to this map. It will automatically sort according to month and day.

Comment: @user2822178, I have updated my full code for your convenience. It was descending order sort.

Comment: It fails if the year is different but month and day are same.

Comment: Yes just tried, it does not add an entry with same date but different years.

Comment: @user2822178, You can't do that, Map does not support duplicate key. Here same date means duplicate.

Comment: Yes I got that, So I am back to my previous approach!

Answer (score 3):

HashMaps are not inherently ordered, so taking out the elements, ordering them, and putting them back in a HashMap will remove the ordering. You can use TreeMap (which is ordered), or use a List or some other ordered mechanism. You could even do something more complicated depending on your requirements like a List of keys (to maintain order) and a Map of key, object (for fast retrieval).

Comment: Sounds interesting but then again I lose the key if I remove the year. I have to overcome that.

Comment: You can create your own Object like 'MyDate' that stores year, month and day as three separate fields. Then you can write your own comparator to do the ordering on the fields you want to order by, and use getters to retrieve the values you want to keep at the end?

Comment: Check out Masud's answer, looks good to me - you can use a comparator to compare the dates using only month and day, but without losing year as part of the original data